# When does validation happen in Core Data?

Tags: iphone, core-data

From the docs:

> If you make changes to managed objects
>   associated with a given context, those
>   changes remain local to that context
>   until you commit the changes by
>   sending the context a save: message.
>   At that point—provided that there are
>   no validation errors—the changes are
>   committed to the store.

So does that essentially mean, that validation happens automatically as soon as I call -save?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, validation is performed by the managed object context on save. You can manually validate an instance at any time by sending it a `-validateFor[Insert|Update|Delete]:`, depending on the action that will occur on context save.

Comment: Oh great! Now I get it! And in case of errors, the NSError out-parameter of -save: will contain those validation error messages?

Comment: Yes, the NSError out-parameter will contain the validation error(s). If there are multiple validation errors, you can retrieve the individual errors from the NSError's `userInfo` dictionary.